# how to search for a word in a docx file in c++?

Tags: c++, file, search, docx

i am writing a search program in c++ which will search for a set of words in a set of files.. these files are either text files or docx files.The problem is how can i search a docx file in c++, i cannot open it even,if i need to convert it to text file, what is the procedure and how will i search it?

Comment: `.docx` is a proprietary file format.  I believe programs like OpenOffice have reverse-engineered it, to some extent.

Comment: @Maxpm `.docx` files are just renamed zip archives containing the document data in the form of xml files, png images, etc. so it's rather easy to open/read them, especially if you don't need a "complete" implementation to read/write all format features etc.

Comment: @Maxpm: actually it's a documented standard, as explained by Jerry Coffin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OOXML file formats are officially documented in [ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm). There's an equivalent ISO standard (29500, if memory serves), but I believe you have to pay to get it, and the two are identical<sup>1</sup>. As a warning, however, these are *huge* documents, and the file formats themselves are definitely non-trivial to deal with. Just getting at the raw text is a *relatively* easy task, but still not exactly trivial.

<sup>1</sup> The ECMA standard was accepted by the ISO under its "fast track" program, where they accept an existing standard intact, even in some cases where it doesn't completely follow the normal ISO guidelines.

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies. Now the problem is that i have a text file which lists contents of drive d, i want to read that file and want only the name of files with a .txt extension in an array. how can i get ?

Answer (score 4):

.docx is zip with a bunch of XML files in it. It's documented at http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/GuidedTourOfSpecPart1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If writing your own OOXML parser is not an option, you could convert your docx files with [docx2txt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docx2txt/) .